# How to create a VR Paint Spray in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am currently working on a VR application in which the player has to paint on a whiteboard using a paint spray.

Through the internet I have found this project and this is exactly what I want to do:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTv6YPWNLxY

This is simply amazing and he shared his git link in description, which leads to a v2 ->  https://github.com/sugi-cho/Unity-ProjectionSpray-v2

But there is my problem... I struggle using his scripts in my project and I don't know why ... I am using the same scripts in the same conditions but nothing happens ...

Here is my project : https://gitlab.com/Julien_Plasteig/vr-paint-spray

All I want to do at this point is to make the spray work, and to see the paint on my object! I can take care of the rest.

If somebody finds what is ( are ) my mistake(s) I'd be grateful !

Thanks :)

[EDIT] Also, this is my first post in StackOverflow, please feel free to tell me if I've done some mistakes here too :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i think I found out what's going on !

In the example I was missing a shader located in the other part ( simpleLight )  and this shader is depthRender...

So, If you are trying to use this don't forget to copy this shader in your project too..

Also you may have to change a little bit SpotDrawer.cs :

```
    Shader depthRenderShader { get { return Shader.Find("Unlit/depthRender"); } }
```

change this line by :

```
    [SerializeField]
private Shader depthRenderShaderPick;
```

And in the editor just drag and drop the shader in the new field
[Where To drag and drop the shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I024B.png)

Hope this helps :)